# How to check if start and end date do not intefere with others start and end dates

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to create function for booking rooms in hotel - one reservation for one room.

One of IN parameters in my function `reservation` is `starting_date` and `ending date` to know when the client want to book room.
Also `reservations` table contains a lot of `beginning` and `ending` dates - because on room can have many reservations.

How to check if is possible to process that dates in reservation request and already reserved dates do not interfere?

My code now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reservation (
    starting_date   IN DATE,
    ending_date     IN DATE,
    room_capacity   IN NUMBER,
    room_category   IN VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER 
--returns room_id or 0 if is no room 
 IS

    v_room_id   NUMBER;
    CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT r.room_id
    FROM  rooms r
        JOIN reservations res ON r.room_id = res.room_id
        JOIN room_category rc ON rc.category_id = r.room_category
    WHERE
        r.capacity = room_capacity
        AND rc.name = room_category 
        --to do--
        ;

BEGIN

v_room_id:=0;
--todo--
return v_room_id;    
END;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use next logic: given appointment does not interfere with referent one either if it start after him or ends before him.

Invert this with `NOT` and you will get intersections:

```
reservations res
....
NOT(starting_date> res.end_date OR ending_date< res.start_date)
```

After applying conversion as Kaushik Nayak mentioned above you will get

```
reservations res
....
NOT(starting_date> res.end_date) AND NOT(ending_date< res.start_date)
```

And finally getting rid of `NOT` with reversing comparison

```
reservations res
....
starting_date<= res.end_date AND ending_date>= res.start_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this to get non-overlapping dates. Use the parentheses carefully.

```
reservations res
..
..
AND
   NOT (   starting_date BETWEEN res.start_date AND res.end_date 
        OR ending_date   BETWEEN res.start_date AND res.end_date 
   OR 
   (
      starting_date    < res.start_date 
      AND res.end_date < ending_date 
   )
);
```

I am not sure if you could simplify this and make it cleaner. But,
give it a try if you want. Use these as your guide.

```
not-(A and B) = (not-A) or  (not-B)
not-(A or B ) = (not-A) and (not-B)
```